# Hive/SQL count occurrences for multiple columns and rows

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm looking for a smart way to count occurrences.

**Here is an example:**

```
 UserID     CityID    CountryID   TagID
 100000      1         30        5
 100001      1         30        6
 100000      2         20        7
 100000      2         40        8
 100001      1         40        6
 100002      1         40        5
 100002      1         20        6
```

**What I wanna do:**

I want to count the occurrences of values columnwise and for each user. In the end I want a table which shows me how many user have more than to different characteristics.

The result should look like this - more or less

```
Different_CityID    Different_CountryIDs   Different_TagIDs
1                   3                      2
```

**Explanation:**

- Different_CityIDs: Just UserID 100000 has different CityIDs
- Different_CountryIDs: All user have different IDs for their country
- Different_TagIDs: Both UserID 100000 and 100002 have different TagIDs. User 100001 has just "6" as TagID.

I struggled with COUNTs for the columns and GROUP BYs but in the end it doesn't work out. Is there a smart solution?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select  count(case when pos=0 and count_distinct_ID>1 then 1 end) as different_cityid
       ,count(case when pos=1 and count_distinct_ID>1 then 1 end) as different_countryid
       ,count(case when pos=2 and count_distinct_ID>1 then 1 end) as different_tagid

from   (select      pe.pos
                   ,count (distinct pe.ID) as count_distinct_ID
        from        mytable t
                    lateral view posexplode (array(CityID,CountryID,TagID)) pe as pos,ID

        group by    t.UserID
                   ,pe.pos        
        ) t          
;
```

---

```
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
| different_cityid | different_countryid | different_tagid |
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
|                1 |                   3 |               2 |
+------------------+---------------------+-----------------+
```

---

Here is another variation that avoids the `count(distinct ...)`

```
select  count (case when pos=0 and not is_distinct_ID then 1 end)  as different_cityid
       ,count (case when pos=1 and not is_distinct_ID then 1 end)  as different_countryid
       ,count (case when pos=2 and not is_distinct_ID then 1 end)  as different_tagid

from   (select      pe.pos
                   ,min(pe.ID)<=>max(pe.ID)  as is_distinct_ID
        from        mytable t
                    lateral view posexplode (array(CityID,CountryID,TagID)) pe as pos,ID

        group by    t.UserID
                   ,pe.pos        
        ) t          
;
```

...and another variation

```
select  count (case when not is_distinct_CityID    then 1 end)   as different_cityid
       ,count (case when not is_distinct_CountryID then 1 end)   as different_countryid
       ,count (case when not is_distinct_TagID     then 1 end)   as different_tagid

from   (select      min (CityID)    <=> max (CityID)     as is_distinct_CityID
                   ,min (CountryID) <=> max (CountryID)  as is_distinct_CountryID
                   ,min (TagID)     <=> max (TagID)      as is_distinct_TagID

        from        mytable

        group by    UserID     
        ) t          
;
```

Comment: Jesus Christ! Thanks @Dudu! That looks strange and I will try it. Never saw "lateral view".

Comment: Your welcome :-) check the updated answer - for educational purposes

Comment: what does '<=>' operator do?  I am not completely clear about what it does based on the explanation in the hive docs.

Comment: Have you checked https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF? I think it is very clear

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code i think it help you,

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT (CountryID)) AS CountryID,
COUNT(DISTINCT(CityID)) AS CityID,
COUNT(DISTINCT(TagID)) AS TagID
FROM test GROUP BY UserID
```

result will be like this,

```
CountryID   CityID  TagID
2   3   3
1   2   1
1   2   2
```

Regards,
Vinu

Comment: Hey Vinu, thanks for your comment. Sadly this is not what I want. If you check the example above I want to extract the amount of user with different characteristics for each columns. It doesn't matter if a user have two or three different characteristics for a country. I just want to check how many users have more than one characteristics. Hopefully you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

`select uid,cid,count(c),count(g) from(select cid,uid,count(coid)                        over(partition by cid,uid) as c,count(tagid) over(partition by cid,tagid) as g from citydata)e group by cid,uid;`

here uid = userid,cid =cityid,coid = countryid,tagid

`Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
OK
uid     cid   coid   tagid
100000   1      1     1
100001   1      2     2
100002   1      2     2
100000   2      2     2
Time taken: 3.865 seconds, Fetched: 4 row(s)`

based on `userid` i hope this will be helpful